# R - replicate weight survey

Tags: r, database, statistics

Currently I'm interested in learning how to obtain information from the American Community Survey PUMS files. I have read some of the the ACS documentation and found that to replicate weights I must use the following formula:

[image]

And thanks to google I also found that there's the SURVEY package and the svrepdesign function to help me get this done

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/3.33-2/topics/svrepdesign

Now, even though I'm getting into R and learning statistics and have a SQL background, there are two BIG problems:

1 - I have no idea what that formula means and I would really like to understand it before going any further

2 - I don't understand how the SVREPDESIGN function works nor how to use it.

I'm not looking for someone to solve my life/problems, but I would really appreciate if someone points me in the right direction and gives a jump start.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `svyrepdesign`, you are specifying that it is a design with replicated weights, and it uses the formula you provided to calculate the standard errors.

The American Community Survey has 80 replicate weights, so it first calculates the statistic you are interested in with the full sample weights (X), then it calculates the same statistic with all 80 replicate weights (X_r).

You should read this: https://usa.ipums.org/usa/repwt.shtml

Comment: Thank you, found a PDF in your link that came really handy